how to swap tokens in tron network using python?
I am new to developing in this direction and programming overall. I would like to know how to swap tokens in TRON network.
For example I want to swap TRX for this token https://tronscan.org/#/token20/TXL6rJbvmjD46zeN1JssfgxvSo99qC8MRT
https://tronpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
I found this but I'm still struggling. I appreciate any kind of help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
